# Plotting this kind of graph in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to plot a graph that looks like this:

[image]

The graph needs to look like two bell curves. There's no specific functions or anything for it.

Here's what I have.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[very thin,color=lightgray,step=0.5cm] (0,0) grid (6.1,3.6);
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (6.2,0) node[anchor=north] {$t$};
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,3.7) node[anchor=east] {$v$};
    \draw
        (0,0) node[anchor=north] {0}
        (1,0) node[anchor=north] {10}
        (2,0) node[anchor=north] {20}
        (3,0) node[anchor=north] {30}
        (4,0) node[anchor=north] {40}
        (5,0) node[anchor=north] {50}
        (0,1) node[anchor=east] {5}
        (0,2) node[anchor=east] {10}
        (0,3) node[anchor=east] {15};
    \draw[thick,color=blue] (0,0) to [out=0,in=180] (1,3);
    \draw[thick,color=blue] (1,3) to [out=0,in=180] (2,0);
    \draw[thick,color=blue] (2,0) to (4,0);
    \draw[thick,color=blue] (4,0) to [out=0,in=180] (5,3);
    \draw[thick,color=blue] (5,3) to [out=0,in=180] (6,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

As you can see it doesn't really look like bell curves.

I'm very new to TikZ and this is the only way I know how to plot. Please help!

Comment: Do you have more details, such as the value of `v` when `t` is `2,4,6,8` or `12,14,16,18`... It will be easier to draw with those value

Comment: It's an arbitrarily drawn graph, no points whatsoever.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE! You can plot arbitrary functions. Note that you'd probably make your life more comfortable by drawing this with `pgfplots`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={Gaussian(\x,\y,\z)=exp(-\z*(\x-\y)*(\x-\y));}]
    \draw[very thin,color=lightgray,step=0.5cm] (0,0) grid (6.1,3.6);
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (6.2,0) node[anchor=north] {$t$};
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,3.7) node[anchor=east] {$v$};
    \draw
        (0,0) node[anchor=north] {0}
        (1,0) node[anchor=north] {10}
        (2,0) node[anchor=north] {20}
        (3,0) node[anchor=north] {30}
        (4,0) node[anchor=north] {40}
        (5,0) node[anchor=north] {50}
        (0,1) node[anchor=east] {5}
        (0,2) node[anchor=east] {10}
        (0,3) node[anchor=east] {15};
    \draw[thick,color=blue] plot[domain=0:2,variable=\x,samples=101]
    ({\x},{3*Gaussian(\x,1,5)});    
    \draw[thick,color=blue] plot[domain=4:6,variable=\x,samples=101]
    ({\x},{3*Gaussian(\x,5,5)});    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Just for fun: a quick pgfplots variant.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={Gaussian(\x,\y,\z)=exp(-\z*(\x-\y)*(\x-\y));}]
\begin{axis}[axis lines=left,grid=major,xmin=0,xmax=72,ymin=0,ymax=22,
xlabel=$t$,ylabel=$v$]
 \addplot[domain=0:20,thick,blue,samples=101] {15*Gaussian(\x,10,0.1)};
 \addplot[domain=40:60,thick,blue,samples=101] {15*Gaussian(\x,50,0.1)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can of course adjust its appearance.

Comment: Ahh. Thanks. I love the pgfplots variant. May I know when I should use tikz and when I should use pgfplots? Is there any resources where I can look up examples for both tikz and pgfplots?

Comment: @StevenSun There is no rule when to use what. However, I'd like to argue that, if one starts to add multiple ticks by hand, it is time to gauge whether one is better off with pgfplots. Both the pgfmanual and the pgfplots manual are very nicely written. Additional examples can be found on this site and on [TeXample](http://www.texample.net/) as well as [pgfplots](http://pgfplots.net/).

Comment: What do you mean by "add multiple ticks by hand"?

Comment: @StevenSun In your example, you have `\draw
        (0,0) node[anchor=north] {0} ....`, the analogous lines are not there in the pgfplots variant.